# Get a variable value from a json decoded response

Tags: php, html, json, response

I have a json response which is decode into an array $data as

```
stdClass Object ( [outboundSMSMessageRequest] => stdClass Object ( [deliveryInfoList] => stdClass Object ( [deliveryInfo] => stdClass Object ( [address] => 8606142527 [deliveryStatus] => Submitted ) [resourceURL] => http://api-testmobile.com/smsmessaging/1/outbound/OPNHSE/requests/urn:uuid:0f55fd13-a419-4ad9-adec-3dcf63ca39c1/deliveryInfos ) [senderAddress] => OPNHSE [outboundSMSTextMessage] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Sam has requested a payment of Rs 10.00. ) [clientCorrelator] => [receiptRequest] => stdClass Object ( [notifyURL] => [callbackData] => ) [senderName] => [resourceURL] => http://api-openhouse.testingmobile.com/smsmessaging/1/outbound/OPNHSE/requests/urn:uuid:0f5-a419-4ad9-adec-3dcf63ca39c1 ) )
```

I want to store `[deliveryStatus] => Submitted`  this "Submitted" into a variable.

I have tried `$dStatus=$data['deliveryStatus'];` but its not working :(

UPDATE

I tried to convert it to associative array by json_decode($data,TRUE);

```
Array ( [outboundSMSMessageRequest] => Array ( [deliveryInfoList] => Array ( [deliveryInfo] => Array ( [address] => 98989 [deliveryStatus] => Submitted ) [resourceURL] => http://api-otest.com/smsmessaging/1/outbound/OPNHSE/requests/urn:uuid:3b277b5b-cf79-4551-872f-16674499bc09/deliveryInfos ) [senderAddress] => OPNHSE [outboundSMSTextMessage] => Array ( [message] => sam has requested a payment of Rs 100.00 through payt.me . Kindly clickhttps://www.test.me/test to pay. ) [clientCorrelator] => [receiptRequest] => Array ( [notifyURL] => [callbackData] => ) [senderName] => [resourceURL] => http://api-test.com/smsmessaging/1/outbound/OPNHSE/requests/urn:uuid:3b277b5b-cf79-4551-872f-16674499bc09 ) )
```

I got this.Now how to get the deliveryStatus variable?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look at the view-source of the HTML you are outputting, or to wrap the `print_r` in a `<pre></pre>` tag, so that you can see the structure more easily.

Also, the elements are of class Object, which means they are not an array, so you need to use `->` to access the elements of your objects.

So if it is an object:

```
$data = json_decode($response);
$dStatus = $data->outboundSMSMessageRequest->deliveryInfoList->deliveryInfo->deliveryStatus;
```

If it is an array, then:

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
$dStatus = $data['outboundSMSMessageRequest']['deliveryInfoList']['deliveryInfo']['deliveryStatus'];
```

You see, the `deliveryStatus` entry is nested in sub-objects in the first case, and in sub-arrays in the second case.

Comment: I tried this but im getting A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/dash.php

Line Number: 138

Comment: You need to know how to debug your code... First, look at line 138, and check the object you are trying to access in there with `print_r`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get that variable fromt he asssociative array.i have updated the question

Comment: In array format, it is the same, but with [] instead of ->, so: $data['outboundSMSMessageRequest']['deliveryInfoList']['deliveryInfo']['deliveryStatus']

Comment: Im actually not getting it,can u update your answer.Im new to json.

Comment: Ya tried this.I am getting undefined index error.Message: Undefined index: outboundSMSMessageRequest

Comment: As I suggested, do a print_r within <pre></pre> tags like this: `<pre><?php print_r($data); ?></pre>`. Then you can see the nested structure clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it a an associative array, you should convert it like an associative array first. Pass `TRUE` as a second argument to `json_decode` function as described in docs: http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're accessing the data in the wrong fashion. json_decode returns an object, so you need to access these fields as object properties. For example:

Instead of

```
$dStatus=$data['deliveryStatus'];
```

Try a member access format

```
$dStatus=$data->deliveryStatus;
```

If you want to access the data as an associated array, that's also quite simple.

When you call `json_decode`, pass `true` as the second parameter:

```
$myJson = json_decode($data,true);
```

Please refer to the [document on json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information.

Comment: I tried the member access format ,but error saying that is an undefined variable.

Comment: Ensure that the member "path" is correct. I haven't had a chance to look at your returned object in detail (trying to watch my 2 year old daughter at the same time :P)

Comment: but Im getting this Message: Trying to get property of non-object '$dStatus=$status->outboundSMSMessageRequest->deliveryInfoList->deliveryInfo->deliveryStatus;
      echo $dStatus;'

Comment: Make sure it's not an array of objects embedded inside, in which case you'll need to use array notation.